# add border on top of image without resizing with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

Here is a 100x67px image of a turtle:

[image: yertle]

If I add a border to my image like so:

```
convert turtle.png -border 50x50 turtle-border.png
```

ImageMagick adds border around my original image, increasing the dimensions to 200x167px.

[image: yertle with border]

How do I paint a border *on top* of my turtle image without resizing the dimeions?  Yes, I know the turtle's head and feet will no longer be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a border that's "eating" into the image, use [`-shave`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#shave) to reduce the image, then [`-extent`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#extent) it back to original size.

```
convert turtle.png -background gray75 \
        -shave 10x10 \
        -extent 100x67-10-10 \
        turtle-border2.png
```

[image: Shave & extent]

**Previous answer**

Use the [`-draw`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#draw) operation to place a rectangle over the image.

```
convert turtle.png -fill gray75 \
        -draw 'rectangle 0 0 100 33' \
        turtle-border.png
```

[image: add border on top of image without resizing with imagemagick]

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it might be using the `-fx` operator like this:

```
convert turtle.png -fx "i<10||i>(w-10)||j<10||j>(h-10)?0:p" out.png
```

That says... *if we are less than 10 pixels from the left of the image, or less than 10 from the right, or less than 10 from the top, or less than 10 from the bottom, output 0 (which is black) else output the original, unaltered pixel colour (p).*

[image]

Change the 0 to 0.75 for a grey instead of black.

[image]

Yet another way of doing it - just a slight simplification of @emcconville's answer:

```
convert turtle.png -shave 10x10 -bordercolor red -border 10 result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Love the FX solution, but `-shave` + `-border` is much more elegant.